# How to check if a document is a valid PDF document

Tags: c#, asp.net, file-upload, upload

I am creating a application, in which user uploading the different types of document on server. I am validating diffrent types of document like jpeg,jpg, PNG, TIF, TIFF, GIF, BMP, ICO.

```
 Dictionary<string, byte[]> imageHeader = new Dictionary<string, byte[]>();
    imageHeader.Add("JPG", new byte[] { 0xFF, 0xD8, 0xFF, 0xE0 });
    imageHeader.Add("JPEG", new byte[] { 0xFF, 0xD8, 0xFF, 0xE0 });
    imageHeader.Add("PNG", new byte[] { 0x89, 0x50, 0x4E, 0x47 });
    imageHeader.Add("TIF", new byte[] { 0x49, 0x49, 0x2A, 0x00 });
    imageHeader.Add("TIFF", new byte[] { 0x49, 0x49, 0x2A, 0x00 });
    imageHeader.Add("GIF", new byte[] { 0x47, 0x49, 0x46, 0x38 });
    imageHeader.Add("BMP", new byte[] { 0x42, 0x4D });
    imageHeader.Add("ICO", new byte[] { 0x00, 0x00, 0x01, 0x00 });
```

The same thing I also want to do for pdf,docx,excel, PPT. Please help me to find the hex code for these documents.

and I also want to validate the corrupted document if someone tries to upload an invalid document.

Comment: Validating docx would be quite complicated, since the main binary format is just a ZIP archive, but the contents are specific. So do you really want to validate it's actually docx, or "possibly docx", meaning a ZIP archive, which might be xlsx, or just a random collection of files? Also a valid PDF document would require actually parsing the whole file, but checking for the start might suggest it might be one.

Comment: i want to validate only above mentioned documents

Answer (score 0):

[`libmagic`](http://www.darwinsys.com/file/) is a library for this kind of thing. It's behind the `file` command in modern Unix systems. You could use it either via FFI/bindings or just look at their [magic number database](https://github.com/file/file/tree/master/magic/Magdir).